# Java Better alignment of fields declarations using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Adding too many fields into a class it becomes a mess like this:

```
private static final int UNAVAILABLE = -1;
private static final int EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 4000 * 4;
private static final int SKIP_INACCURACY_SIZE = 1200;
private Thread thread = null;
private Object dataSource;
private AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
private AudioInputStream encodedAudioInputStream;
private int encodedAudioLength = -1;
private AudioFileFormat audioFileFormat;
private SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;
```

I want Eclipse to reformat the code and make it better to read so I modified default formatter and have achieved this:

```
private static final int                UNAVAILABLE             = -1;
private static final int                EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE    = 4000 * 4;
private static final int                SKIP_INACCURACY_SIZE    = 1200;
private Thread                          thread                  = null;
private Object                          dataSource;
private AudioInputStream                audioInputStream;
private AudioInputStream                encodedAudioInputStream;
private int                             encodedAudioLength      = -1;
private AudioFileFormat                 audioFileFormat;
private SourceDataLine                  sourceDataLine;
```

But it's still messy and I can't find how to modify the editor further to achieve this (you can see the difference in `static`)

(Found this piece of code [here](https://github.com/HanSolo/submitbutton/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/hansolo/submitbutton/SubmitButton.java) and I think it can be even more improved to create and an empty column for `final`):

[image]

Image of the Editor in Eclipse:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: The first thought was _"switch to COBOL"_, but I can understand. However not even 0.01% of the fellow java programmers will have experienced such a formating and appreciate it. If you want to work with others better live with the scrubby java code.

Comment: @Joop Eggen It's clear and beautiful for eyes.For the usual code i have to open search window :).

Comment: *"Modified the Tags cause the code contains also JavaFX Classes."* If only the code that you want to format contains JavaFX classes, but not the formatter and you're not trying to achieve some special formatting for JavaFX classes, the `javafx` tag is misleading here, since it would not matter, if the code contains `ObjectProperty<Color>` or `List<BigInteger>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Field Declarations in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570415/formatting-field-declarations-in-eclipse)

Comment: @DVarga Thanks for help but i have already done that(`as shown in the final image`),although it needs improvement and the suggested answer doesn't contain anything new.

Comment: It's likely far from trivial. I just fiddled around with this. The option to select a block of variable declarations and format them ("nicely"!) with a dedicated menu command may be reasonable. In any case, there are open issues: What should happen for `int final x=3; final int y=3;`. Should modifiers be reordered? But for a *real* formatter, one would have to dive into http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/formatter/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/formatter/linewrap/FieldAligner.java etc. I tried it, but ... not the slightest chance of getting anywhere there.

Comment: @Marco13 About `int final x=3; final int y=3;`,better to keep it in the second way with final at the beginning.I had a look into the file in jdt core.So thats what had to be modified to get the result above?It has not even comments...Except two general.

Comment: The question aimed at how the `final` and `int`in these two declarations should be aligned, or whether the formatter should also *reorder* the modifiers (it could, with some `ASTRewrite`).

Comment: I *think* that the `FieldAligner` would be a point where some modifications would have to be made. The "entry point" would likely be http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/formatter/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/formatter/DefaultCodeFormatter.java . But as I said: There's no chance for just messing around with a few lines of code and achieving this result. The lack of comments is a joke, and the concepts around the parser and token manager are nearly impossible to understand in reasonable time if you're not already familiar with this part of the code.

Comment: IMO messing with spaces is less readable, I prefer to arrange the fields and methods in `regions` that explain what they're for if I have many. You can also collapse them which makes navigation easier.

Comment: @kuhaku The final example in the question can be further more improved to alight even better the fields.Why you think it is not readable?I am using it (until example 2 i am able to format it) and it is easy to understand from the optical view. Also i like your way too.I think a combination of the above and your way is perfect.Add it as answer,so i can see better what you mean...;)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to write your own formatting program that takes a file location as input and writes formatted content back to the same file. It can be made as an eclipse plugin that can run on a particular key stroke.
The upside is that you can customize the way you want.
The downside is that it would be re-inventing the wheel if someone already had done it.

Comment: Yes creating a Plugin would be great but it needs time and good knowledge , except of complexity . This will be the last solution if someone hasn't already done it...

Answer (score 0):

When I run into formatting issues like this my first reaction is "is this class doing too much?".

Through repeated application of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) you should be able to trim down the number of fields to a readable number - and such that no special formatting is required.

Comment: James thanks for the answer,i readed your link.Sometimes a class which exists to do only one think can have a lot of variables.Here in this question i want a general formatter to make the code more wonderfull and human readable.